# Android, open web browser intent only from certain activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app with an activity (MainActivity) that needs to be able to open links in textviews, which ive done with Linkify.
I also have an activity (Activity2) that uses a webview to interact with a webpage that uses html buttons and javascript to do things. However, after pressing one of the html buttons, the site wants to open a new page, resulting in the "Complete this action using..." dialogue.

I want the dialogue to come up in MainActivity, but not Activity2. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `WebViewClient` on your `WebView` in the second `Activity`. For example:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```